# .Net Native - Type not included in compilation

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, .net-native

I found weird warning messages during .net native compilation for Universal App Platform - Windows 10.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(886,5): warning : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'XT.Controls.VideoPlayer.VideoPlayerControl'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(886,5): warning : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'XT.Controls.VideoPlayer.VideoPlayerControl'. There may have been a missing assembly.

Application is not working correctly in release mode. I get crash after splashscreen with MissingMetadataException that requires to debug RuntimeType.cs (missing).

Any ideas how can I include these types in compilation?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600640%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Hans,
I've added parameters like this:

 `<Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls" Dynamic="Required Public" Serialize="Required Public" Browse="Required Public" Activate="Required Public" />` 

I am still getting compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

In connection to Hans link problem is solved by this line of code.
Added to project properties Default.rd.xml

```
<Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" Serialize="Required Public" Browse="Required All" Activate="Required All" />
```

Comment: You can probably simplify your directive to this one: <Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />. Browse and Activate are subtypes of "Dynamic" and you almost certainly don't need serialization information for all the types in Windows.UI.Xaml. There are also cases where having overly broad directives can trip up the .Net Native compiler unnecessarily. HTH